# Table self related query

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a table which has self relationship:

id -- parentId  columns

I need a query to get the parent row where the parentId is null, but I couldn't figure out the proper way of doing this.

```
select * from table1 where id = parentId;
```

Apparently this is not working, it will just give the direct parent.

Any help

Comment: This doesn't make sense: "get the parent row where the parentId is null" - if the parentId is null, doesn't that mean that there is no parent row ?

Comment: You can do it with a recursive CTE: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243.aspx

Comment: @driis: I think he means get the "super"-parent. The parent of the parent of the parent until there are no more parents.

Comment: It the "super" parent the row you need to find, ie. traverse the hierarchy to the top from some node ? Then a recursive CTE is the way to go, at least if you are in a SQL flavor that supports it (MSSQL 2005 and up).

Comment: A hint on SQL tag on SO: If you give us sample data and expected results data, you will get an answer presto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"Get the parent row where the parentId is null"* makes no sense, but in case you actually meant *"get the parent row **until** the parentId is null"*, then this recursive [CTE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_table_expressions) should do the trick:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id = 7
    UNION ALL
    SELECT table1.* FROM table1 JOIN cte ON table1.id = cte.parentId
)
SELECT * FROM cte
```

This returns the row with id = 7 and all its ancestors recursively. Replace 7 according to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *

FROM table1 AS A

LEFT JOIN table1 as B
  ON B.ID = A.parentID

WHERE B.parentID IS NULL
```

Comment: it didn't bring all the results
some rows where missing

Comment: Maybe add an example of what you are looking for :)